# MPI Barrier C++

Tags: mpi, barrier

I want to use MPI (MPICH2) on windows. I write this command:

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And I expect it blocks all Processors until all group members have called it. But it is not happen. I add a schematic of my code:

```
int a;  
if(myrank == RootProc)  
   a = 4;  
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
cout << "My Rank = " << myrank << "\ta = " << a << endl;
```

(With 2 processor:) Root processor (`0`) acts correctly, but processor with rank 1 doesn't know the `a` variable, so it display `-858993460` instead of `4`.

Can any one help me?
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only assigning `a` in process 0.  MPI doesn't share memory, so if you want the `a` in process 1 to get the value of 4, you need to call `MPI_Send` from process 0 and `MPI_Recv` from process 1.

Comment: Thanks. It's true, but I have another question. As I know barrier blocks the caller until all group members have called it, but I tested and saw that process 1 pass this function (by writing a sentence, cout) and root process (0) is before the barrier. What's the problem? Thanks

Comment: You can't trust the order of output statements from different processes.  If you're unsure, make sure your clocks are sync and output `time()` before and after the barrier.

Comment: Don't expect clocks on different processors to be in such close synchronisation that the times they report allow you to correctly sequence output statements.  The MPI_Barrier synchronises processes, not clocks.

Comment: Until you've done a lot of MPI programming, like a couple of year's solid practice, I don't think you should even let it cross your mind that the MPI_Barrier is not working correctly.  All the MPI libraries I have ever used were written in organisations with high reputations for product quality.  If you think there is something wrong with a barrier, it is overwhelmingly more likely that you have made a mistake (in thinking or in coding) than that the barrier itself is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `a` is not initialized - it is possible that is why it displays that number. In MPI, variable `a` is duplicated between the processes - so there are two values for `a`, one of which is uninitialized. You want to write:

```
int a = 4;
if (myrank == RootProc)
...
```

Or, alternatively, do an `MPI_send` in the Root (id 0), and an `MPI_recv` in the slave (id 1) so the value in the root is also set in the slave.

<strike>Note: that code triggers a small alarm in my head, so I need to check something and I'll edit this with more info. Until then though, the uninitialized value is most certainly a problem for you.</strike>
Ok I've checked the facts - your code was not properly indented and I missed the missing `{}`. The barrier looks fine now, although the snippet you posted does not do too much, and is not a very good example of a barrier because the slave enters it directly, whereas the root will set the value of the variable to `4` and then enter it. To test that it actually works, you probably want some sort of a sleep mechanism in one of the processes - that will yield (hope it's the correct term) the other process as well, preventing it from printing the `cout` until the sleep is over.

Answer (score 1):

**Blocking is not enough**, you have to send data to other processes (**memory in not shared** between processes).

To share data across ALL processes **use**:

```
int MPI_Bcast(void* buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm )
```

so in your case:

```
MPI_Bcast(&a, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

here you send one integer pointed by &a form process 0 to all other.
//**MPI_Bcast is sender** for root process and **receiver** for non-root processes

You can also send some data to specyfic process by:

```
int MPI_Send( void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, 
              int tag, MPI_Comm comm )
```

and then receive by:

```
int MPI_Recv(void* buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)
```